# Flutter/Dart http client - conent type header is sent twice

Tags: http, dart, post, header, content-type

Any simple network call with default Dart http client, for example, sign out request:

```
Future <void> signOut() async {

  final body = jsonEncode(SignOutRequest()..deviceId = await DeviceId.getID);

  String authHeader = globals.token.tokenType + " " + globals.token.accessToken;
  
  await http.post(globals.url + '/auth/sign_out',
      headers: {HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: globals.apiVersion,
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: globals.apiVersion,
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: authHeader},
      body: body);

}
```

And from what I see my actual headers are:

```
accept:api-version
accept-encoding:gzip
authorization:bearer token
content-length:31
content-type:api-version; charset=utf-8
Content-Type:api-version; charset=utf-8
```

So content type is set 2 times (content-type and Content-Type). If I don't set any content type, text/plain is set twice. Is that some kind of bug, or intended?